# ios swift 2 how to populate uipickerview with json data

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am new to iOS development and using swift language. In my application I am using Alamofire 2 networking library for calling rest api's. Now I want to populate uipickerview dynamically, I am calling this web service and getting response as json array

```
[
 {
    duration = "2017 - 2018";
    year = 2017;
 }
 {
    duration = "2016 - 2017";
    year = 2016;
 }
 {
    duration = "2015 - 2016";
    year = 2015;
 }
]
```

Now I want to populate the uipickerview with "duration" data, I have gone through various examples but not able to understand how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Swift code:

```
 func getYear()
{
    url = baseUrl + "/foo/bar"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url , parameters: ["foo": foo,"bar":bar])
        .responseJSON(){
    (_,_,result)
            in
            print("get year list result ",result)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
                let jsonData = JSON as! NSDictionary
                let duration = jsonData.objectForKey("duration")
                print("duration ",duration)

            case .Failure(let data, let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

                if let data = data {
                    print("Response data: \(NSString(data: data, 
                    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)")
                }
            }

    }

}
```

Console message

```
get year list result  SUCCESS
Success with JSON: 
(
        {
        duration = "2017 - 2018";
        year = 2017;
    }
)

Getting this error
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x394c92d0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x394c93c0).
```

Thank you

Comment: Show your attempts and errors pls.

Comment: Parse the JSON data to store all the duration values in an array and use this array in your implementation of the UIPickerViewDelegate functions

Comment: Yes @DSDharma it is a duplicate question, as I have said I am new to iOS development and gone through ur suggested example, but unable to get Json Array data.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the data into an array :-

```
yourModel : NSObject {
var duration: String?
var year : String?
}
```

Suppose:  `yourArray = [yourModel]()`

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
      return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
     return yourArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
     if yourArray.count > 0 {
        return yourArray[row].duration
    }
 }
```